# Sort php multidimensional array by key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have the below multidimesional array.

```
Array
(
[2] => Array
    (
        [66] => Array
            (
                [id] => 66                    
                [count] => 9
            )
        [255] => Array
            (
                [id] => 255                    
                [count] => 20
            )            

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [59] => Array
            (
                [id] => 59                
                [count] => 14
            )

        [255] => Array
            (
                [id] => 255                   
                [count] => 73
            )
    )    
)
```

I want to sort the inner array by value of count key in descending order.
How can I achieve it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sort Multi-dimensional Array by Value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2699086/sort-multi-dimensional-array-by-value)

Comment: see below answer, hope it will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try below solution:

```
<?php
$array = Array
(
'2' => Array
    (
        '66' => Array
            (
                'id' => 66 ,                  
                'count' => 9
            ),
        '255' => Array
            (
                'id' => 255,                    
                'count' => 20
            )            

    ),

'1' => Array
    (
        '59' => Array
            (
                'id' => 59,                
                'count' => 14
            ),

        '255' => Array
            (
                'id' => 255,                   
                'count' => 73
            )
    )    
);

echo '<pre>';

foreach($array as &$ar){
usort($ar, function($a, $b) {
    return $b['count'] - $a['count'];
});
}

print_r($array);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 255
                    [count] => 20
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 66
                    [count] => 9
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 255
                    [count] => 73
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 59
                    [count] => 14
                )

        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example:

Sort Multi-Dimensional Array By Value In PHP
https://paulund.co.uk/sort-multi-dimensional-array-value

Comment: Link-only-answers are not very well received around here. Pages that are linked have a habit of going away over time. Please provide at least a summary of the important bits of what you are linking to.